# How to make a spinner work using Spin.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spinner

Hello guys,

I am new at JavaScript and after tons of research on the Internet and failed attempts on implementing a spinner I decided to ask you.

I am using Spin.js ( http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/#v1.2.6 ). It seems to be an great tool, but I simply cannot make it work. My question is what I doing wrong? I cannot really figure it out. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Here is my piece of code:

```
   <script src="Scripts/Spin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
           function spinnerInit() {
               var opts = {
                   lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
                   length: 7, // The length of each line
                   width: 4, // The line thickness
                   radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
                   corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
                   rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
                   color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
                   speed: 1, // Rounds per second
                   trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
                   shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
                   hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
                   className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
                   zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
                   top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
                   left: 'auto', // Left position relative to parent in px
                   visibility: true
               };

               var target = document.getElementById('spinnerContainer');
               //target.style.display = "block";
               var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
           }
       </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#btnPerformSave').click(function () {
                   spinnerInit();
               });
           });
       </script>

     <div id="spinnerContainer" class="spinner" style="width: 100%; height: 150%;
           position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: Gray;
           left: 0; top:  0; bottom: 0;right: 0">
       </div>
```

Comment: Nothing stands out at first glance. You could add some console.log() to try to find where the problem is. Per exemple, is JQuery included in your code ? Is your click event registered ?

Comment: The Spin.js is included (you can see it at the top of my piece of code). Also, the click event works just fine (the save operation is performed as it should) but the spinner doesn't appear even though the save operation takes some time 5-6 seconds. Thanks for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 16):

Try replacing

```
var target = document.getElementById('spinnerContainer');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
```

with

```
$('#spinnerContainer').after(new Spinner(opts).spin().el);
```

You need to append the html element the spin method creates to the dom

Here is an example to get you started http://jsfiddle.net/5CQJP/1/

Comment: Apparently, my code is very stubborn and it simply doesn't want to work, despite of the > 10 versions I have tried so far. Anyway, thank you :)

Comment: If you need to stop it then you need to save the instance of new Spinner to a variable and then call the stop method.

Comment: I tried "$('#spinnerContainer').after(new Spinner(opts).stop().el);"

It didnt work for me.Help !!

Comment: @Shashank Example of spinner spinning for 2 seconds.
    var s = new Spinner(opts);
    $('#spinnerContainer').after(s.spin().el);
    setTimeout(s.stop.bind(s), 2000);

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure if this question ever got answered, but for those who are still looking for an answer:

I found out that I needed to move the javascript underneath the spinnerContainer div. I believe this would also work if you put the javascript in an onload event. Here is what I did:

```
<div id="spinnerContainer" class="spinner" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color: Gray;">
</div>
<script src="Scripts/Spin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var opts = {
      lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
      length: 7, // The length of each line
      width: 4, // The line thickness
      radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
      corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
      rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
      color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
      speed: 1, // Rounds per second
      trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
      shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
      hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
      className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
      zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
      top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
      left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
    };
    var target = document.getElementById('spinnerContainer');
    var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
</script>
```

Comment: The spinner is displayed at the top left corner . How to position it?

Comment: @SundeepSaluja: try { top: '50%', left: '50%' } .[Refer] (http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/) for more details

Comment: var target2 = document.getElementById('spinnerContainer');
var spinner2 = new Spinner(opts).stop(target2);

It is not stopping the spinner.Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer. Works great.

```
//Declare Script
<script src="Scripts/spin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


 <button  id="btnSearchClick">Search</button>

//Displays Loading Spinner
<div id="loading">
    <div id="loadingcont">
        <p id="loadingspinr">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
     //On button click load spinner and go to another page
     $("#btnSearchClick").click(function () {  
        //Loads Spinner
        $("#loading").fadeIn();
        var opts = {
            lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
            length: 7, // The length of each line
            width: 4, // The line thickness
            radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
            color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
            speed: 1, // Rounds per second
            trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
            shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
            hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
        };
        var trget = document.getElementById('loading');
        var spnr = new Spinner(opts).spin(trget);

        //Go another page.
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var target = document.getElementById('spinnerContainer');
           //target.style.display = "block";
           var spinner = new Spinner(opts);
```

If you use jQuery:

```
           $(target).html(spinner.el);
```

If not, as in the documentation:

```
           target.innerHtml = '';
           target.appendChild(spinner.el);
```

I didn't try this but it should work. If a problem occurs, just let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). I have tried both versions, but the spinner still doesn't appear. I have no idea why isn't this working,because I am pretty sure the script is good (the reviews were great), but I siply don't know where my mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way late but I am curious if you ever got this to work. I'll tell you one dumb thing I was doing for a bit and didn't realize it. I was making the spinner the same color as the background it would be showing up against and that's why I couldn't see it. Also I used JQuery as seen here https://gist.github.com/its-florida/1290439
Worked like a charm

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Eventually I discovered that, due to the way my application was constructed, I had a callback at a certain moment that cancelled my spinner. Actually, the spinner was working, but due to the fact that the callback used to occur quite fast, I wasn't able to actually see it working.